# IE8 Browser Bootstrap work only responsive mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I IE8 browser Bootstrap change automatically responsive mode. how to change basic web view. Plz help me.

Comment: But i try this method also. it's not  work

Comment: I'm sure that not supporting media queries will cause your problem. You should at least share your code to get an answer. Better build a fiddle or bootply to show your problem live.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer versions before IE9 do not support media queries.

A crappy solution would be change the css style sheet by JavaScript when Width goes below "your queries".